# How to get variable calculated in one function from another class

Tags: python

I have class like this:

```
class oneClass:

   def func():
      ...
      angle = int(result)
      ...
      return img
```

As you can see `func()` is a kinda long function, and inside of it I calculate `angle`. I can't change it, I have to `return img`.

What I want to do, is access `angle` variable from another class, which is in another script, in same folder, like this:

```
class anotherClass():
   def anotherFunc():
      oneClass.func.angle
```

idk somethin like this. Is it possible? I tried to make `angle` as global var in `oneClass`, but it didn't seem to work, I'm a beginner in python.

Comment: Well maybe the problem is that `func` is a long function. Why don't you have a function (or even better, property) `angle` on your class, that can be used by `func` and elsewhere?

Comment: ^ hard to say more with the minimal info you gave

Comment: it all has to be in the same function, what I mean by "long" is that angle is calculated by using multiple variables in the same function.

Comment: Why are you forced to use bad design?

Comment: Just to add a bit of information: You cannot fetch a local variable from a method directly that way. You have to either store `angle` as an attribute of `oneClass` (or an instance of it) or store it in another location.

Comment: if you want to access to angle, best way is refactor the func to return the tuple. return img, angle. Any other solution will not be good. What you want to do is antipattern.

Comment: Is `angle` calculated with other attributes contained in `oneClass`? If so, then maybe a `@property` decorator could be used to dynamically create it?

Comment: @PeterTrcka i didn't know it is possible to return 2 variables from function. if so, how to use a returned angle in another class?

Comment: `img, angle = func()` and `func()` is returning  `return img, angle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning img return angle as well. Return tuple:

```py
class oneClass:

   def func():
      ...
      angle = int(result)
      ...
      return img, angle
```

use:

```py
class anotherClass():
   def anotherFunc():
      img, angle = oneClass.func()
```

Comment: if `anotherFunc` only depends on `angle` and `img` is expensive to calculate, this would be improved by making a separate method `calc_angle` that is invoked in `func`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class MyClass:
  def func(self):
    angle = 1
    self.angle = angle
    img = angle +10
    return img

test = MyClass()
test.func()
print(test.angle)
```

Comment: this is not good. In threads, `self.angle` can be incosistent. Value can be changed by other function call before the original value was extracted.

Comment: @PeterTrcka I'm not sure threading are the topmost concern here

Comment: @anon01, threads was just an example. changing class attributes inside public function is a bad idea. To achieve the goal is that function return tuple of img and angle. If user has the power to add attribute he can modify the function output.

Comment: agree this isn't the cleanest, threads just isn't the most important issue here.  Also, there are no class attributes in the above code.